# File not found : sap-ui-cachebuster-info.json

Tags: sapui5, sap-web-ide

The file `sap-ui-cachebuster-info.json` is not getting generated. I have tried putting `data-sap-ui-appCacheBuster="../"` in `index.html`, also trued changing every possible path for the same parameter.

I am facing this issue in SAP Web IDE. I have just downloaded the SAP Web IDE (Eclipse Orion) and ran the `Orion.exe`. I have created a (Create from Sample Application) UI5 Sample application and haven't added any customized code but when I am running it, I am getting the below exception:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not found: http://localhost:8080/file/samdhiman-OrionContent/Demo2App/sap-ui-cachebuster-info.json) send @ jquery-dbg.js:9203

Index.html:

```html
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo2App</title>
    <script id="sap-ui-bootstrap"
      src="../../resources/sap-ui-core.js"
      data-sap-ui-libs="sap.m"
      data-sap-ui-theme="sap_belize"
      data-sap-ui-compatVersion="edge"
      data-sap-ui-appCacheBuster="./"
      data-sap-ui-resourceroots='{"Demo2Demo2App": "./"}'>
    </script>
    <script>
      sap.ui.getCore().attachInit(function() {
        new sap.m.Shell({
          app: new sap.ui.core.ComponentContainer({
            height: "100%",
            name: "Demo2Demo2App"
          })
        }).placeAt("content");
      });
    </script>
  </head>
  <body class="sapUiBody" id="content"></body>
</html>
```

Because of this issue, Routes are not working.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `data-sap-ui-appcachebuster` from `index.html` altogether since app cache buster is handled already by Web IDE internally (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58749798/5846045)). The URL config `sap-ui-appCacheBuster` will be added accordingly in the address bar by Web IDE when the app is launched.